# VS Code debug '__Invoke-ReadLineForEditorServices' is not recognized

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Using VS Code Version: 1.44.2 (system setup).

```
$error.clear()
Write-Host "this is the error message"
Write-Host "the result is $($?)"
$null -eq $LASTEXITCODE
Write-Host "lec is $($LASTEXITCODE)"
$LASTEXITCODE
```

I have used $error.Clear() before starting debug.

```
PS C:\src\t> $error.clear()

PS C:\src\t> $error

PS C:\src\t> c:\src\t\Trap.ps1
                        ### debugging started, beak on first statement, $error already has an entry
[DBG]: PS C:\src\t> $error

The term '__Invoke-ReadLineForEditorServices' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
[DBG]: PS C:\src\t>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an official bug, that is long known and not fixed yet.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices/issues/1295